# extract specific data from json array using php curl

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

I have a json file that I would like to extract a couple of lines from the array to build a list of events.  The json is grabbed using curl.

I can get a dump of the file but don't know how to isolate specific fields from the array.

The data looks like this and I would like to just extract the  Name, Url & IsPublic

```
    {
    "Forms":[
    {
    "Name":"BRIO Tuscan Grille",
    "Description":"Event descripton here\n\nHosts: Dave ",
    "RedirectMessage":"Great! Thanks for filling out my form!",
    "Url":"brio-tuscan-grille",
    "Email":"email@email.com",
    "IsPublic":"1",
    "Language":"english",
    "StartDate":"2000-01-01 12:00:00",
    "EndDate":"2030-01-01 12:00:00",
    "EntryLimit":"9",
    "DateCreated":"2013-09-30 09:00:09",
    "DateUpdated":"2014-02-10 06:35:41",
    "Hash":"123456",
    "LinkFields":"https:\/\/mysite.com\/api\/v3\/forms\/123456\/fields.json",
    "LinkEntries":"https:\/\/mysite.com\/api\/v3\/forms\/123456\/entries.json",
    "LinkEntriesCount":"https:\/\/mysite.com\/api\/v3\/forms\/123456\/entries\/count.json"
    },


//This is the requesting page
<?php
$curl = curl_init('$url');       
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                          
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'AUTHCODEHERE:footastic');   
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);                     
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Forms XML');             

$response = curl_exec($curl);                                           
$resultStatus = curl_getinfo($curl);

if($resultStatus['http_code'] == 200) {
    echo htmlentities($response);
} else {
    echo 'Call Failed '.print_r($resultStatus);
}


?>
```

Comment: could use `$item = json_decode($array);` and access the resulting object like: **`$item->name`**

Comment: [php.net/json](http://php.net/json).